# Easy way to store and retrieve data

Tags: javascript, c++, json, database, sqlite

I'm working on this project that requires my team and I to do a state of the art of existing Bluetooth modules and their characteristics. I thought it would be easier for us if we could just find a way to store everything we'll find in a programming interface, that is, we would just have to input the new data to a form and it would automatically update the underlying storage structure.

We need to be able to easily extract the created content and export it to .txt or .tex. The method used need to be easy to use, this is only a small part of the project and we don't have time to learn complex tools.

I know Javascript and a bit of C++. At first, I thought of creating an HTML form and use Js to take the input and add it to a JSON file that would then be transformed into an HTML table. This approach seems broken to me though, we wouldn't be able filter anything without writing lines of code and getting data from an HTML file with C++ must be a pain in the a**. Also, the JSON data would be in the browser local storage which is really not a good idea.

I also used SQLite a bit some years ago, and I remember that it is easy to filter the data. Does it sound like a good option to you ? Is it easy to add/retrieve data into/from an SQLite database ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Why not write Javascript that takes the form data and posts it back as CSV or tab-separated text? You are not bound to JSON with JS. I'd write a couple of lines in PHP (yes, the language is ugly, but it's easy to learn if you know JS) that generates the HTML form, then  accepts the post-back and updates a SQLite DB.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to write on a text file with JS. How is it possible ? I'd need Node.js don't I ? Also, what do you mean by "accepts the post-back and updates a SQLite DB" ? If I don't want to learn PHP, is it possible to update an SQLite DB with Javascript ?

Comment: You can't directly write text files with browser JS. You need some kind of backend, either node or PHP or Java that updates the DB. This backend receives the HTTP POST from your HTML form.